Virtual solvability of dense subgroups
Let $G$ be a (finitely generated) dense subgroup of $\mathsf{SL}(2;\mathbb{C})$. Is it possible that $G$ is virtually solvable?
In other words, by Tit's alternative, does being dense necessitate the existence of a nonabelian free subgroup in $G$?

Where did this question come from. Context please.

I was reading about Tit's alternative, and trying to understand the structure of dense subgroups of SL(2;C) as given in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8153159. In trying to understand the possibility of elementary subgroups, I was reading about solvable/virtually solvable subgroups, and wondered how Tit's alternative interfaced with these results.

What do you think? What can you say about the closure of a solvable subgroup in a general topological group?

I think I see, it would seem that the closure would also have to be solvable.

Then try to prove it, this is not hard. Start with the abelian case.
